# How to order elements when accesed by many to many relation in pythons SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, many-to-many, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

Assuming two models in a many to many relationship:

```
parent_child = Table('parent_child', metadata,
                         Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id')),
                         Column('child_id', Integer, ForeignKey('children.id')))

class Parents(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True} # reflecting database

    children = relationship('Child',
                          secondary=parent_child,  # What goes here for sorting?
                          backref='parents')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True} # reflecting database
```

I know I can do

```
parent = session.query(Parent).first()
```

to get the first parent element in the table. Doing

```
parent.children
```

returns all children of the given parent. **What if I want to sort them let's say by birthdate (assuming the model `Child` has column `birthdate`)?**

Answer (score 0):

there's an `order_by` keyword argument available for relationship. [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#relationships-api)

Answer (score 0):

Also your missing the `s` in the `parent = session.query(Parents).first()` and the `s` in the ForeignKey

```
children = relationship('Child', secondary=parent_child, order_by='Child.birthdate', backref='parents')
```